# Fetch specific informations from complex json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I want to fetch year, category, id and share of a particular nobel prize winner from the json data, by giving firstname and surname as raw input. I am able to get id and share easily from the below code but how can I get year and category.
Here is my code:

```
  var json = {"prizes":
[{"year":"2018",
"category":"physics",
"overallMotivation":"\u201cfor groundbreaking inventions in the field of laser physics\u201d",
"laureates":[
{"id":"960",
"firstname":"Arthur",
"surname":"Ashkin",
"motivation":"\"for the optical tweezers and their application to biological systems\"",
"share":"2"},
{"id":"961",
"firstname":"G\u00e9rard",
"surname":"Mourou",
"motivation":"\"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses\"",
 "share":"4"},
  {"id":"962",
 "firstname":"Donna",
 "surname":"Strickland",
 "motivation":"\"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses\"",
 "share":"4"}
 ]}
 ]};

var winner = json.prizes.reduce((acc, winners) => 
(acc.push(...winners.laureates), acc), []).find(i => i.id === '960')
console.log(winner);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I have added miultiple prizes in my test input. I hope that is allright. Try this code.

```
const input = {
  prizes: [
    {
      year: "2018",
      category: "physics",
      overallMotivation:
        "\u201cfor groundbreaking inventions in the field of laser physics\u201d",
      laureates: [
        {
          id: "960",
          firstname: "Arthur",
          surname: "Ashkin",
          motivation:
            '"for the optical tweezers and their application to biological systems"',
          share: "2"
        },
        {
          id: "961",
          firstname: "G\u00e9rard",
          surname: "Mourou",
          motivation:
            '"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses"',
          share: "4"
        },
        {
          id: "962",
          firstname: "Donna",
          surname: "Strickland",
          motivation:
            '"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses"',
          share: "4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      year: "2019",
      category: "chemistry",
      overallMotivation:
        "\u201cfor groundbreaking inventions in the field of laser physics\u201d",
      laureates: [
        {
          id: "960",
          firstname: "Arthur",
          surname: "Ashkin",
          motivation:
            '"for the optical tweezers and their application to biological systems"',
          share: "2"
        },
        {
          id: "961",
          firstname: "G\u00e9rard",
          surname: "Mourou",
          motivation:
            '"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses"',
          share: "4"
        },
        {
          id: "123",
          firstname: "Donna",
          surname: "Strickland",
          motivation:
            '"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses"',
          share: "6"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function find(firstName, surname) {
  return input.prizes.map(prize => {
    const filteredLaureate = prize.laureates.filter(
      laureate =>
        laureate.firstname === firstName && laureate.surname === surname
    );
    return filteredLaureate.map(i => {
      return {
        id: i.id,
        share: i.share,
        category: prize.category,
        year: prize.year
      };
    });
  }).flat();
}

const response = find("Donna", "Strickland");
console.log(response);
```

Comment: I am getting error for flat function: `input.prizes.map(...).flat is not a function`.

Comment: where are you using the flat function as it not supported everywhere?. You could look for workaround as well.

Comment: could use this as well in place of `flat`
`[].concat.apply([], response)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
let winners = [];
json.prizes.forEach(e => {
  let data = { year: e.year, category: e.category };

  const laureates = e.laureates.find( item => {
    return item.firstname === 'Arthur' && item.surname === 'Ashkin';
  });

  data = { ...data, ...laureates };

  winners.push(data);
});

console.log(winners);
```

The code above will give output like this:

```
[{
  category: "physics",
  firstname: "Arthur",
  id: "960",
  motivation: "\"for the optical tweezers and their application to biological systems\"",
  share: "2",
  surname: "Ashkin",
  year: "2018"
}]
```

Remember, the code above will not perform very good when the dataset is large.

Comment: what changes need to be done when dataset is large. @Dijkstra

Comment: I believe the complexity of my code is `O(n^2)`. So, you have to find  some better data structure to perform the find operation optimally.